# can't activate rspec (~> 2), already activated rspec-3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

using rspec i'm receiving the following error when trying to run rake:

> monkey:00_hello steventaylor$ rake
>
> (in /Users/steventaylor/Desktop/learn_ruby-master)
>   rake aborted!
>   Gem::LoadError: can't activate rspec (~> 2), already activated rspec-3.0.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.

i'm new to ruby and rspec and have know idea how to solve.

i have uninstalled rspec (incl core, expectations, mocks & support) and reinstalled.

i've also looked around at similar posts that mention 'rspec -include-dependencies', i've tried this and this does not seem to help either.

maybe i'm tired and missing something REALLY simple, but i would love any suggestions!

thanks in advance!
-steven.

this is my gem list...

[image]

```
Gems included by the bundle:
```

* bundler (1.6.3)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * rake (10.3.2)
  * rspec (3.0.0)
  * rspec-core (3.0.2)
  * rspec-expectations (3.0.2)
  * rspec-mocks (3.0.2)
  * rspec-support (3.0.2)

Comment: run rake/rails/rspec command with `bundle exec`. So in your case you should run `bundle exec rake`

Comment: I second @gotva's response. Mostly this kind of message happens when your system rake is different to the version of in your local bundle of gems

Comment: thanks, I tried 'bundle exec rake', but received the same error.

Comment: post your `bundle list`. also post your `spec_helper.rb` (and `rails_helper.rb` if you have it)

Comment: bundle list: 'Could not locate Gemfile'

Comment: `
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|

#   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
    expectations.syntax = :expect
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
    mocks.syntax = :expect


    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
=end
end
`

Comment: /rails_helper.rb does not exist.

Comment: @TarynEast thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Do you have a Rails application? or it is just a ruby application? if it is Rails app then I think you should start from [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Your problem is in missed `Gemfile` but if you generate a new app (`rails new my_app`) Gemfile is generated automatically. So I can't understand how you generate new app without Gemfile.

Comment: in the file i'm using the gemfile is:

Comment: monkey:learn_ruby-master steventaylor$ bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.6.3)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * rake (10.3.2)
  * rspec (3.0.0)
  * rspec-core (3.0.2)
  * rspec-expectations (3.0.2)
  * rspec-mocks (3.0.2)
  * rspec-support (3.0.2)

Comment: i'm not sure why it would not show previously, 4am operator error is my guess.

Comment: Heya - code formatting in comments is truly awful... really hard to read. Any chance you can edit your question and add that there instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

I found through further searching that reverting to a rspec version < 3.0.0 solved the issue.

command used: `sudo gem install -v '< 3.0.0' rspec`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while trying to "use an earlier" rspec version for a class.  Un-installing and reinstalling rspec did not work.

It seemed the error/message had to do with bundler. I found this on the RVM website(I use rvm and I have a mac/latest OS)
There is no need to do anything to make bundler work with RVM, but there is one thing about bundler that makes it harder to use. By default, bundler does not generate wrappers for gem binaries. To make use of the proper version of a gem binary, users are forced to prefix every command with bundle exec. This makes working in the console rather painful. Fortunately, there are solutions that allow us to just write binary names; the binary from 'gem' specified in the Gemfile will be used.

This fixed my problem:

To make all the executables bundler compatible run:

gem regenerate_binstubs # only once

Now as far as what happens if u do more than once...I did not want to find out...